# Use virtual property in interface (EF)

Tags: entity-framework, interface

How can I use a virtual property in an interface in Entity Framework?:

```
public interface ICommentable
{
    int CommentableId { get; set; }
    virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

That throws an error for the virtual keyword, but if I do it this way:

```
public interface ICommentable
{
    int CommentableId { get; set; }
    ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Then this (below) throws an error ("does not implement ...")

```
public class Something : ICommentable
{
    int CommentableId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    ...more properties....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It throws an error because `CommentableId` is not `public`. It has nothing to do with placing `virtual` on `Comments` in the class which is valid.

Using virtual in interface is not valid because it doesn't make sense. When you define interface, the implementing class must implement all its members. Virtual keyword means that derived class can override existing implementation but the interface has no implementation.

Comment: It doesn't throw an error because of CommentableId not being public, it throws an error because "public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }" is not what the interface is imposing to implement, ie: without the virtual.